# How can I display/hide a div based on taxonomy term value on node.tpl.php file?

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I am not a dev, but am trying to show and hide a div for on a particular node type node.tpl.php file based on taxonomy term value.

can someone please let me know how to do this.

****I AM ADDING THE ANSWER HERE AS I AM NOT ELIGIBLE FOR ANSWERING ****

I have a div which prints the taxonomy value of a node (where 30 is the vacabulary ID):

```
    <div class="node-r-status-tid-0 <?php print $term_css;?>">
        <?php print THEME_NAME_taxonomy_list($node, 30); ?>
    </div>
```

Below is the PHP code to make the dive show and hide:

```
    <?php 
    if ($node->taxonomy[868])
      $tid = 868;  // This should be the taxonomy term id that you want to theme on
        foreach ( (array)$node->taxonomy as $term ) {
          if ( $term->tid == $tid ) {
            $term_css = " node-r-status-tid-" . $term->tid;
            break;
          }
        }

    if($node->taxonomy[869])
      $tid = 869;  // This should be the taxonomy term id that you want to theme on
        foreach ( (array)$node->taxonomy as $term ) {
          if ( $term->tid == $tid ) {
            $term_css = " node-r-status-tid-" . $term->tid;
            break;
          }
        }
    ?>
```

Using css classes I make the dive display:block or none.

Please let me know if the above code can be fine tuned further

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: Please post the DIV structure.

Comment: it is just a normal div with static content in it.

Comment: Please post the taxonomy links html structure and div you are talking about.. Ideal way is using jquery you can do that !!

Comment: I think I got it now...

There is a div in node.tpl.php file, lets say eg: 

<div class="node-r-status-tid-0 <?php print $term_css;?>">Some content</div>

Comment: I have added this code   <?php 
  if ($node->taxonomy[868])
    $tid = 868;  
   foreach ( (array)$node->taxonomy as $term ) {
     if ( $term->tid == $tid ) {
    $term_css = " node-r-status-tid-" . $term->tid;
    break;
     }
   }
 
  if($node->taxonomy[869])
    $tid = 869;  
   foreach ( (array)$node->taxonomy as $term ) {
     if ( $term->tid == $tid ) {
    $term_css = " node-r-status-tid-" . $term->tid;
    break;
     }
   }
  ?>

Comment: So using a I have a single div and I am setting node tid as the css value, since I have two terms I have to repeat the same if loop again with another hard-coded term ID, and using css on style.css i make dive visible and hide for both the classes :)

Comment: Please let me know of the code can be fine tuned further..
Thanks,

Comment: @AnAnD hi, just curious, why did you write _you're not eligible to post the answer_. I think you should be.

Comment: @indrock http://drupal.stackexchange.com has stopped accepting answers from me, so I put my answers below the question, actually by re-editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 6 add somthing like this to your template.

```
foreach ($node->taxonomy as $term ) {
  if ($term->tid == YOUR_TID) {
     print "<div>...</div>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works.. :) I was trying to round, round and round to get to my destination :D